# Sum group by label in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have a set of data with various stock symbols and would like to know how many bullish and bearish signals there were for each symbol for each day.

How would I do this with Pandas? Thanks

```
Input:      
Date    Symbol  Sentiment
5/2/19  GE      Bullish
5/2/19  GE      Bullish
5/2/19  GE      Bearish
5/2/19  GE      Bearish
6/2/19  GE      Bullish
6/2/19  GE      Bullish
6/2/19  GE      Bullish
6/2/19  GE      Bullish
6/2/19  GE      Bullish
6/2/19  GE      Bearish
6/2/19  GE      Bearish
6/2/19  GE      Bearish



Output:         
Date    Symbol  Sentiment Bullish   Sentiment Bearish
5/2/19  GE      2                   2
6/2/19  GE      5                   3
```

Comment: can you post the data as text please. :)

Comment: Specifically, see question 9, using `.pivot_table` with `aggfunc='size`, i.e. `df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'Symbol'], columns='Sentiment', aggfunc='size')`

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Thanks.

Comment: `crosstab` is really well suited for this too: `pd.crosstab(index=[df.Date, df.Symbol], columns=df.Sentiment)`. Also possible with `.groupby`.

Comment: Wonderful. I was just about to make a Date, Symbol index but this works too. Thanks